# Using ExpressJs, How can i proxy certain host only and for everything else just render the request?

Tags: node.js, express, proxy

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy')

var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.host === dev.app.com) {
    proxy.web(req, res, { target: req.url })
  } else {
    // don't proxy request
    // just render the page
  }
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

This is what I have for now, I tried reading through express js docs, but fail to understand on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, I believe you should just call `res.render('your-page-here');` (In the case if you are using a template engine, like Pug or ejs)

Or, if you are going to serve a static page, `res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');` for example.